# Approach miniumum when I lost WAAS during approach

Tags: flight-controls, instrument-flight-rules, approach, gnss, waas

I have a GPS receiver with WAAS.
During an LPV approach, I received an LOI message
That means I only lost WAAS, not RAIM.
Did I just need to change minimum to LNAV and continue the approach?

Comment: What avionics do you have?

Answer (score 1):

where were you at on the approach when you received the LOI message?  This is my understanding:

- Outside the FAF, adjust minimums as necessary for the new procedure (LNAV/VNAV or LNAV) depending on the mode the WAAS GPS fell down to.
- Inside the FAF, immediately execute missed approach procedures.

The importance of a stabilized approach cannot be over-emphasized.  If you are below 1,000 FT AGL on an instrument approach and something changes, it is often better to go-around than adjust to the change.  Approach landing accident reduction (ALAR) research confirms the importance of a stabilized approach.

Having to switchfrom a vertically guided descent with a missed approach altitude set in the altitude alerter to a non-vertically guided approach where you must adjust the altitude alterter, and possibly flight director / autopilot modes below stabilized approach alititude could be unsafe in my opinion.

Comment: I think the key point here is that this is your opinion. There is no way I would execute a missed just because I lost the capability of following vertical guidance. This is no different than flying an ILS and converting it to a LOC if the glideslope goes out.  When cleared for the approach, you are cleared for all lines of minima.  Also, do you have any links for non-commercial operations and ALAR? I haven’t yet found where this is applicable to either GA or military flying.